# Getting Error: Failed to parse Dockerrun JSON file: json: invalid use of ,string struct tag, trying to unmarshal unquoted value into int

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I used JSON linter to check the validity of this json and it says ok. But when I deploy this to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, it errors out with message:

> Error: Failed to parse Dockerrun JSON file: json: invalid use of
>   ,string struct tag, trying to unmarshal unquoted value into int

Below is `Dockerrun.aws.json`:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "delivery-slot-notifier",
      "image": "akshaylokur/delivery-slot-notifier:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "containerPort": 8080
        }
      ],
      "memory": 128
    }
  ]
}
```

Any clues?

Thanks

Comment: Is that the complete file or a part of it?

Comment: That’s the complete file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be seeing that error in your logs because your Dockerrun.aws.json has a bunch of options are not supported by Beanstalk (looks like you are using multi container docker-run for single container?). Also, for single docker env, Version has to be 1, whereas 2 is used for multi container env. Here's a Dockerrun.aws.json that will work:

```
 {
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "akshaylokur/delivery-slot-notifier:latest",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "hostPort": 8080,
      "containerPort": 8080
    }
  ]
}
```

Here are all the supported [options for Dockerrun.aws.json](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html)

Comment: To find the options on the link, scroll down to `Configuration for Docker platforms (without Docker Compose)` and click on `Docker platform Configuration - without Docker Compose` then on `Dockerrun.aws.json v1`. (not sure why AWS tries so hard to make this hidden...  )